# How do I do a `git checkout` that removes the adds?

Tags: git

I know I can do

```
git checkout my-branch .
```

to replace all the files that have been modified on my branch.  It works fine with the modified files, but if I had files on my current branch that were added, it had kept them.

Is there a way of doing the `git checkout` such that the *adds* are not done?

Workflow:

1. Steps to get to the state before the operation

```bash
git init test
cd test
touch a
touch b
touch c
git add .
git commit -a -m "Initial"
echo "My name is A" > a
git commit -a -m "Changed name"
git checkout -b my-branch
echo "My name is B" > b
git commit -a -m "Changed name in branch"
git checkout master
echo "My name is B" > b
touch d
git add .
git commit -a -m "changed name in master and added file"
```

From this point I want decided I want `my-branch` (which does not have `d` to be what's on `master`.  What I would normally do is

```
git checkout my-branch .
```

but doing that does not delete `d`.  So I wanted something that would delete `d` ideally making my `HEAD` == `my-branch`

Comment: Can you give an explicit workflow to show what you mean? I can't seem to reproduce this - adds disappear for me after a git checkout.

Comment: `checkout` in the form of `git checkout <commit> <files>` cannot remove files, it can only add or replace files.

Comment: correct is there another command I can use?

Comment: Probably git reset maybe with the --hard option if I understand your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply delete everything in your repo (except the `.git` directory) and then do the checkout:

```
git rm -rf .
git checkout my-branch .
```

After that, `d` is deleted:

```
➜  test git:(master) ✗ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    deleted:    d
```